# Perform dirty checking on collection using GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am attempting to detect changes to an collection in such a way that I can trigger the creation of new objects.  For example, an Inventory has many Items.  An item has a name and a quantity.  I am able to detect an add/remove from a items using dirty checking.

```
//Detecting add/change
inventoryInstance.items.isDirty()
```

I am having difficulty identifying a change to the associated Item object (name, quantity) as well as an order change in items. isDirty() does not appear to identify these changes.  I am using Grails 1.3.7 and I am using grails data-binding via an HTML form and indexed field names ( items[0].name, items[0].quantity).  Does anyone have a suggested solution or an alternative approach?

Example domain classes:

```
class Inventory {
  List items = new ArrayList()

  static hasMany = [items:Item]
  static constraints = {
    items(size:0..10)
  }
  static mapping = {
    items cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }
}

class Item {
  String name
  Integer quantity = 1
  Boolean deleted = false

  static transients = ['deleted']
  static belongsTo = Inventory
  static constraints = {
    name blank:false
    quantity size:1..100
  }
}
```

Controller

```
def inventoryInstance = Inventory.get(params.id)

if( inventoryInstance ) {
  inventoryInstance.properties = params

  // Check for add/removes, this works.
  def isDirty = inventoryInstance.items.isDirty()

  if(!isDirty) {
    // Check items in list for changes, does not work..
    inventoryInstance.items.each { item ->
      if(item.dirtyPropertyNames) isDirty = true
    }
  }

  if(isDirty) {
    //do something...
  }

  inventoryInstance.save(flush:true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that does something similar to what you are asking for:

```
        def taskChanges = []
        requestInstance?.tasks?.each { task ->
            taskChanges << [task,
                    task?.dirtyPropertyNames?.collect {name ->
                        def originalValue = task.getPersistentValue(name)
                        def newValue = task."$name"
                        log.debug "$name : old:: $originalValue , new:: $newValue ."
                        [(name): [originalValue: originalValue, newValue: newValue]] //returned and added to taskChanges list
                    }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Your code makes sense but does not seem to work for me and I'm assuming it has something to do with the way that I'm doing data-binding. I added some controller code so that you can see what I'm encountering.  I never see any dirty property names.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: check your logic ... its a bit difficult to follow and you are also overwriting isDirty variable that doesn't seem appropriate. Your databinding looks fine. Comment out your code and do this to debug:    log.debug "dirty check after params binding  :  ${inventoryInstance.items.isDirty()}"
        log.debug "${inventoryInstance.items*.dirtyPropertyNames}"